# Wrong array size when using xlsread in Matlab

Tags: database, excel, matlab

Did anyone come across a similar problem with a wrong array size when using xlsread in Matlab? I do the following:

```
Parameters = xlsread('Results_daily','A1:BD100');
```

Yet Parameters will be of size 14,55.
Could the problem arise because I have empty lines in the Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html

Yes, xlsread's first argument is always the numerical output. It will strip any text or empty lines. If you want the text or full outputs you should call

```
[~,text,full] = xlsread(file);
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the help file but I didn't understand it... The ~ would be what, and what is text and full? Is there a way that I load one big array called Parameters that contains all the output and then simply call various (numerical!) cells like Parameters(1,3) etc?